# Showing that an infinite product is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Let $a_n = 1-\frac{1}{n^2}, g_n (z)= \frac{a_n -z}{1-a_n z}= 1-\frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1+z}{1-a_n z} $

$$ f(z)= \Pi_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n(z)  $$

Show that $f(z) $ is holomorphic and that $f$ does not have an analytic continuation to any larger disk $D(0,r) , r > 1$

I'm not sure how to show the holomorphicity of a function like $f$ as it is a complicated infinite product. Are there any pertinent facts about infinite products to which I could appeal to? What about the second part about not having any analytic continuation?

Comment: An infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+u_n(z))$ is holomorphic in the unit disc if each $u_n$ is holomorphic and if for each $0\leq \rho<1$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sup_{|z|\leq\rho}|u_n(z)|<\infty$ (essentially, we're comparing an infinite product of $1+u_n$ to the infinite sum of the logarithms $\log(1+u_n)$, but to first order this is equivalent to the infinite series $\sum u_n$... all of this should be easily found in books like Ahlfors or Cartan or Rudin).

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo . Do you have any suggestions for the part about analytic continuation?

Comment: think about the zeros of $f$, and what happens if $\lim a_n=1$ is an interior point of a connected set where the function is holomorphic?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks.